# "Not a map for `map-get`" error after adding new elements to a mapping

Tags: sass

How can I merge a mapping into an existing mapping in sass?

I am currently using sass maps in a `_config` partial to define my breakpoints, for example:

```
$breakpoints: (
    small: 35rem,
    medium: 55rem,
    large: 75rem,
    xlarge: 90rem,
    element-breakpoint-1: 100rem,
    element-breakpoint-2: 110rem 
);

@mixin breakpoint($width) {
    @media screen and (min-width: map-get($breakpoints, $width)) {
        @content;
    }
}

.element {
    width: 100px;
    @include breakpoint(element-breakpoint-1) {
        width: 200px;
    }
    @include breakpoint(element-breakpoint-2) {
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

Ideally I would like to be able to add new breakpoints to the existing mapping:

```
@function array-append($list, $value) {
    @return join($list, $value);
}

$breakpoints: array-append($breakpoints, (element-breakpoint-1: 100rem, element-breakpoint-1: 110rem));
```

The issue is that the breakpoint mixin does not see the new values in the `$breakpoints` list and SASS throws the following error:

> Error: $map: (("small" 35rem), ("medium" 55rem), ("large" 75rem), ("xlarge" 90rem), ("element-breakpoint-1" 100rem)) is not a map for `map-get'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `map-merge()`, not `join()`.  The `join()` function is for joining lists together and is causing your mapping to get converted to a list of lists.

```
$fix-mqs: false;
$breakpoints: (
    small: 35rem,
    medium: 55rem,
    large: 75rem,
    xlarge: 90rem
);

// map-merge here, not join
$breakpoints: map-merge($breakpoints, (element-breakpoint-1: 100rem, element-breakpoint-2: 110rem));

@mixin breakpoint($width) {
    @if $fix-mqs {
        @if $fix-mqs >= map-get($breakpoints, $width) {
            @content;
        }
    }
    @else {
        @media screen and (min-width: map-get($breakpoints, $width)) {
            @content;
        }
    }
}

@include breakpoint(element-breakpoint-2) {
  .foo {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 110rem) {
  .foo {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: OooOOOooo this looks promising! Will gives this a whirl when I get back to the office.